# Search a string with German characters in JSON file with PHP

Tags: php

JSON file:

```
{"verbs":[{"_id":1,"option1":"ändern","option2":"öl","option3":"über","answer":"über"},{"_id":2,"option1":"mit","option2":"aus ","option3":"zu","answer":"aus "}]}
```

Code:

```
<?php

  $string = file_get_contents("http://xyz-abc.com/xyz.json");
  $arrays = json_decode($string,true);

   $found = array_search( "ändern", array_column( $arrays, 'option1' ) );
if( $found === False ) echo "Not Found";

else   echo $data[$found]['option1'];
```

I am searching for "ändern" in JSON file. I am getting the output: NOT FOUND. Can anyone find the error in my code?

Comment: I don't know if this is the answer but you are missing a quote at `option1":`

Comment: Thank you for the reply ..I think its typo error while copying from original file.  I will edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
<?php
$string = '{"verbs":[{"_id":1,"option1":"ändern","option2":"öl","option3":"über","answer":"über"},{"_id":2,"option1":"mit","option2":"aus ","option3":"zu","answer":"aus "}]}';
$arrays = json_decode($string,true);

foreach ($arrays as $array) {
    $needle = "ändern";
    $found = array_search($needle, array_column($array, 'option1'));

    if($found === false) {
        echo 'Not Found: ' . $needle; 
    } else {
        echo 'Found: ' . $needle;
    }
}
```

You could not find anything because you did not treat `$arrays` as multi dimensional array, the `$arrays` you search in look this way:

```
array(1) {
    'verbs' =>
    array(2) {
    [0] =>
    array(5) {
        '_id' =>
        int(1)
        'option1' =>
        string(7) "ändern"
        'option2' =>
        string(3) "öl"
        'option3' =>
        string(5) "über"
        'answer' =>
        string(5) "über"
    }
    [1] =>
    array(5) {
        '_id' =>
        int(2)
        'option1' =>
        string(3) "mit"
        'option2' =>
        string(4) "aus "
        'option3' =>
        string(2) "zu"
        'answer' =>
        string(4) "aus "
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Now, I am getting  warning --- Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/a8107d60/public_html/arraysearch.php on line 6 . What could be the reason?

Comment: that's because you don't pass an array to foreach, check if `json_decode` gives you an array, perhaps this way `print(is_array($arrays));` this should print true

Comment: print(is_array($arrays));
print(is_object($arrays));
I tried both .. nothing is displayed ... $arrays is not an array and not an Object ..How to convert $arrays to an  array?

Comment: @Madhu sorry, don't print but use `var_dump(is_array($arrays));` and you should see that is bool `false`